# NavGraph exit animation not playing

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, animation, navigation

I tried to set up a navgraph and tried to animate the transitions between the fragments. Everything works fine, but the exit animation is not playing.

Here is the navigation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment2">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment2"
    android:name="com.example.test.LoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment2_to_signupFragment23"
        app:destination="@id/signupFragment2"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/signupFragment2"
    android:name="com.example.test.signupFragment"
    android:label="signupFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signup">
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

---

Here is the kotlin code to start the animation from the first fragment (loginFragment2):

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_signupFragment23)
```

---

So it is a very simple slide animation, the animation code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromXDelta="0%p"
android:toXDelta="-100%p">
</translate>
```

---

My navHost in the activity is this:

```
<fragment
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
android:id="@+id/loginFragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

---

I know that FragmentContainerView plays animations better than a normal fragment as a container, but when I change it, I get some errors.
(View android.widget.FrameLayout{XXX} does not have a NavController set)

So why is the exit animation not playing? The popExit animation works fine, just when I replace first fragment with the second, the first does not move and the second one just slides over it.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I had a FragmentManager in the onCreate method of the activity, which replaced the fragment placeholder with a fragment. This is normally all done with the navigation component, as I removed the FragmentManager, everything worked fine for me.

Comment: I am having this trouble after Gradle update to 6.7.1 while using only the Navigation component!!
Did you encounter this again?